# Setup Database Context for Entity Framework 6 using Environmental Variables

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, database-connection

I'm having challenges connecting to a remote MySQL database server from an ASP.NET WebAPI 2 app using Entity Framework code first, on Azure.

It works fine on my local server.

Here is the connection string from Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AngryUsersContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=mydbhost;port=3306;database=test_db;uid=gq_user;password=*****" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is part of the context class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class AngryUsersContext : DbContext
{
    public AngryUsersContext() : base("name=AngryUsersContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AngryUsersContext, AngryUsers.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AngryUsers.Models.Complaint> Complaints { get; set; }

    ...
```

I did set up a connection string on application settings. I tried Type: Custom and MySQL but none worked.
[image]

I think my code is supposed to load the connection string from environmental variables to use and connect to the database. I don't know how to modify my context class to achieve that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think my code is supposed to load the connection string from environmental variables to use and connect to the database. I don't know how to modify my context class to achieve that.

When publish your project from Visual Studio and click up this option `Use this connection string at runtime(update destination web.config)` then it will **Cover the local connectionstring with connectionstring on portal** you provided above.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/).